# How to create a fixture for test functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, automated-tests, pytest

I am trying to create a fixture for those functions but I keep getting no tests were found an empty suite.
Maybe I'm doing something wrong but see the code below and what I have tried.

```py
import pytest
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class TestExample:
    def test_open_browser(self):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/")
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "nav-hamburger-menu").click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='hmenu-content']/ul/li[10]/a/div").click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Beading & Jewelry Making").click()
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@id='n/12896151']/span/a/span").click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "a-autoid-0-announce").click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "s-result-sort-select_2").click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                            "//div[@id='search']/div/div/div/span/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/h2/a/span").click()


def test_simple_customer_review(driver, expected_min_score=4):
    try:
        review_score = driver.find_element(By.ID, "acrCustomerReviewText")
        assert review_score >= expected_min_score
    except NoSuchElementException:
        assert False
    except ValueError:
        assert False


def test_price(driver, expected_price_limit=3500):
    try:
        price = driver.find_element(By.ID, "corePriceDisplay_desktop_feature_div")
        assert price <= expected_price_limit
    except NoSuchElementException:
        assert False
    except ValueError:
        assert False

# driver.close()

# if review_score >= "4"
# assert True

# if  price <= "4000"
# assert True
```

I know to access the `fixture` function the test has to mention the fixture name as input parameters.
Maybe I need more explanation on how to do that the code is above.
Please don't be offended guys I am just in a weird and lost situation.

```
@pytest.fixture()
def test_open_browser(self):
return
    
@pytest.fixture()
def expected_min_score=4()
return


@pytest.fixture()
def expected_price_limit=3500
return
```

Comment: what is the name of your file?  if you are just running `pytest` from the command line then it will only automatically detect the tests if filenames start with `test` or `test_`  for example `test_selenium.py`

Comment: The name of my test file is test_main I am running the test inside the IDE (pycharm)

Answer (score 0):

A fixture is just a regular python function, a basic one would have no parameters and return an object or data that you want to use in your test.

for example if you wanted to test your selenium driver...

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver

@pytest.fixture
def driver():
    wd = webdriver.Chrome()
    return wd

def test_google_com(driver):
    driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
    assert driver.current_url == 'https://www.google.com/'
```

an even simpler example would be

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def hello_world_string():
    return 'Hello World!'

def test_hello_world_string(hello_world_string):
    assert 'Hello World!' == hello_world_string
    assert isinstance(hello_world_string, str)
```